# Adding two tags A and B in edit (B substr. of A), B is ignored

Tags: support, tags, edits

I wanted to add the tags `random` and `random-sample` to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663000/choose-k-from-n-with-a-probability), previously only tagged with `algorithm`.

No matter what I tried, `random-sample` is ignored while `random` was added.

Is there any filtering / conflict-resolution in use? Or what else is going on? I did not find anything related in [the tagging-docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

(In my opinion both tags (in combination) are valuable additions here.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[random-sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/random-sample) is a synonym of [random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/random).